# doppl SOInterface is not visible from class loader error

Tags: doppl

I am getting an error with the doppl [SOAndroid app](http://doppl.co/docs/AddingDoppl). I have successfully been through the PartyClickerSample.

```
iosApp[40373:656090] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JavaLangIllegalArgumentException', reason: 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface co.doppl.so.api.SOInterface is not visible from class loader'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef0c12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b51ff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   doppllib                            0x0000000108b2d0a6 JavaLangReflectProxy_getProxyClass0WithJavaLangClassLoader_withIOSClassArray_ + 1791
    3   doppllib                            0x0000000108b2d233 JavaLangReflectProxy_newProxyInstanceWithJavaLangClassLoader_withIOSClassArray_withJavaLangReflectInvocationHandler_ + 45
    4   doppllib                            0x0000000108aab120 -[Retrofit2Retrofit createWithIOSClass:] + 240
    5   doppllib                            0x0000000108ac39c5 SOARepository_init + 389
    6   doppllib                            0x0000000108ac4134 new_SOARepository_init + 52
    7   doppllib                            0x0000000108ac3bb0 +[SOARepository initialize] + 64
```

Why is the SOInterface not visible when it is in the config?

```
...
include 'co/doppl/so/api/**'
...
translatedPathPrefix 'co.doppl.so.api', 'SOAPI'
```

Also with the iosTest, the tests pass but get some BoringSsl statement:

```
********** Result for co.doppl.so.RepositoryTest **********
Success
Total: 1
Failures: 0
2018-02-23 09:50:58.086219-0600 iosTest[41775:778685] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
```

Answer (score 1):

I keept searching and found the answer:

https://github.com/doppllib/SOAndroid/issues/1

"Need to add 'prefixes.properties' to the main app bundle". 
Same as was done with the testIOS app.